# С# взаимодействие потоков

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Как реализовать обмен данными между основным циклом и потоками? 
Допустим есть такой псевдокод
Пример:

```
namespace First
{
    public class Test
    {
     public static string Outout1 = string.Empty;
     private static System.Threading.Thread SThread;

     public static string Func1() 
        {
               pass;
        }

     public static void GetTimeNow()
        {
           for(;;){
            Outout1 += Func1(); 
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
           }
        }

     public static string GetTimeNow2()
        {
             pass;
        }

        private static void RunThread()
        {
            if (SThread == null || SThread.ThreadState != System.Threading.ThreadState.Running)
            {
                SThread = new System.Threading.Thread(GetTimeNow);
                SThread.Start();
            }
        }

        public static void MainFunc()
        {
         for(;;){
         Outout1 +=  GetTimeNow2();
         RunThread() ;
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
         }         
        }
   }
}
```

Запускается главная функция `MainFunc` в бесконечный цикл в этом цикле вызываем функцию `GetTimeNow2`. Которая возвращает нам  данные в переменную `Outout1`.
Далее запускает функцию `RunThread` которая запускает функцию `GetTimeNow` в отдельном потоке.

В функции `GetTimeNow` бесконечный цикл, и в нем вызывается `Func1`, которая пишет данные в `Outout1`.

Вопрос будут ли всегда корректные данные в переменной `Outout1`, а именно будут ли видны данные от `GetTimeNow2` и `GetTimeNow` и если обнулить ее в конце цикла она так же обнулится в `GetTimeNow` которая запущена в отдельном потоке? 
Пример:

```
 for(;;){
     Outout1 +=  GetTimeNow2();
     RunThread(); 
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
     Outout1 = "";
     }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно реализовать данный способ , что бы можно было работать с переменной Outout1 как в основном цикле так и в цикле который запущен в отдельном потоке? и как сделать сделать если запустить не 1 поток а 2-5
Пример:

```
    for(;;){
     Outout1 +=  GetTimeNow2();
     RunThread(); 
     RunThread1(); 
     RunThread2(); 
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
     Outout1 = "";
     }
```

Comment: Если возможно, стоит избегать разделяемых между потоками переменных. Расскажите лучше о смысле вашей задачи.

Comment: хочу разгрузить основной цикл, т.к не которые задачи не обрабатываются во время из-за того что то идет обратка данных в цикле в других функция. Поэтому решил все трудоемкие операции вынести в отдельные потоки , но с возможностью возвращать данные после обработки в перменную Outout1 и работать с этой перменной  в основном цикле

Comment: А давайте вылезем ещё на уровень выше. Забудем о переменной. У вас есть вычисление. Какие данные вы хотите получать в процессе вычисления? Зачем вам, например, промежуточные данные, а не результат?

Comment: Идет обработка счетчиков, которые меняются с большой скорость. Бывают такие ситуации когда одна функция в цикле начинает обрабатывать один счетчик , с другого счётчика она пропускает событие из-за того что основной поток занять обработкой первого счетчика. По этому и хочу вынести обработку 4 счетчиков в отдельные потоки что бы не мешать основному циклу. На основании промежуточных данных вношу изменения в переменную. Если условия попадает под фильтр в промежуточных данных вношу изменения в Outout1.

Answer (score 1):

Как один из вариантов - можно использовать асинхронное программирование с использованием ключевых слов async и await. Результат вы получите тот же без необходимости создавать потоки и без риска получить состояние гонки из за разделяемой переменной. Вот псевдокод:

```
public class MyTestClass
{
    public static string outputString = String.Empty;

    public static string GetFirstString()
    {
        return "world";
    }

    public static string GetSecondString()
    {
        return "!!!";
    }

    public static async Task FirstTimer()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            outputString += GetFirstString();
            await Task.Delay(50);
        }
    }

    public static async Task SecondTimer()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            outputString += GetSecondString();
            await Task.Delay(50);
        }
    }

    public static string GetStartString()
    {
        return "Hello ";
    }

    public static async Task MyMain()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1 ; i++)
        {
            outputString += GetStartString();
            await FirstTimer();
            await SecondTimer();
            await Task.Delay(500);
            Console.WriteLine(outputString);
            outputString = String.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Проверить его можно или в UnitTest-е
Например так :

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestAsyncLoop()
    {
        await MyTestClass.MyMain();
    }
```

Либо в консольном приложении

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    await MyTestClass.MyMain();
}
```

Примечание 1: в консольном приложении применить async к функции Main появилась только с версии компилятора C# 7.1 В других версиях компилятора нужно использовать

```
public static void Main ()
{
    MyTestClass.MyMain().Wait();
}
```

Примечание 2: в приложениях с графическим интерфейсом нужно использовать асинхронные методы с учетом контекста выполнения, что бы не попасть в состояние взаимоблокировки.

Comment: Эээ... Ну async/await — это хорошо, но запись в разделяемую переменную без блокировки — это плохо. Async/await тем и хорош, что можно из `Task`'а возвращать значение и не думать о синхронизации.

Comment: Вопрос о работе с разделяемой переменной из нескольких потоков. Как ваш ответ с этим коррелирует? У вас ни бесконечных циклов нет, ни параллельности, ни ответа на поставленный вопрос

Comment: С async/await  конечно хорошо, но мне бы просто вернуть данные из потока в переменную, мне интересен сам процесс такой манипуляции для опыта т.к. тема потоков не простая, поэтому и обратился сюда к специалистам